# Python variables defined

Tags: python

Consider 
Example1:

```
numbers = [ 1,2,4,5,7,8,3]
for val in numbers:
    sum = 0
    sum = sum + val
print("The sum is: ",sum)
```

The output for the above code is : 3

Example2:

```
numbers = [ 1,2,4,5,7,8,3]
sum =0
for val in numbers:
     sum = sum + val
print("The sum is: ",sum)
```

The output for this code is : 30

What is the difference when sum is defined outside the for loop and inside the for loop ?

Comment: In the first piece of code, you are reseting sum to 0 for each value in the list.

Comment: Well, what a loop means is that the code inside it (the indented code - 2 lines in the first example, 1 line in the second one) runs a number of times - in this case once for each element in the list. So have a think about what the two bits of code actually do, in order - if necessary, get a piece of paper and write down the value of the `sum` variable each time it changes (this is quite feasible with such a simple example) - and you'll soon see what the difference is.

Comment: @HarshPatel Umm, what? There are no local variables involved here.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Sorry, My bad.

Answer (score 0):

sum inside loop:
If you decalre sum=0 inside the loop it will take and print last value of array
numbers = [ 1,2,4,5,7,8,3]
for val in numbers:
    sum = 0
    sum = sum + val

print(sum)
3
sum outside loop:
it will assign evertime the sum value from your looping value the sum value stores globally and incrementing again and again based on your for loop
numbers = [ 1,2,4,5,7,8,3]
sum=0
for val in numbers:
    sum = sum + val

print(sum)
30